# Rails encryption: danpal/attr_encryptor key generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

Using the danpal fork of attr_encrypted.

```
attr_encrypted  :col_int, :key => 'key', :if => :encryption_required, :marshall => true
```

Does the `'key`' string generate a new object with a new session? Since I have ran into a problem where I have created an instance with the encrypted value and it works fine. However when I run a new rails console session or for example try and access the value through a view I get a `bad decrypt` error. I am guessing it is related to having an incorrect key? As in the new session will pass a different string object as the key?

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in not reading the documentation, an extra `col_int_salt` and `col_int__iv` columns are required